# Access to structure field in another structure

Tags: c++, struct, c++14

Suppose I have structures

```
struct A
{
  int x;
};
```

and it is possible to refer to x field by 
`&A::x`

My question is, Can I do something similar (refer to x) in case below (C++14)? :

```
struct A
{
  struct B
  {
    int x;
  };

  B b;
};
```

---

Okay, so there's more complex example:

This works:

```
struct A
{
    int x;
};

template <typename U, typename V, typename W>
void setField(U& object, V U::* field, W&& value)
{
    object.*field = std::forward<W>(value);
}

int main()
{
  auto x = 5;
  A a;
  a.x = 0;
  std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
  setField(a, &A::x, x);
  std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
}
```

and when I want to get deeper variable, it doesn't:

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        enum myEnum
        {
            E_0 = 0,
            E_1 = 1
        };
        myEnum e;
    };
    B b;
};

template <typename U, typename V, typename W>
void setField(U& object, V U::* field, W&& value)
{
    object.*field = std::forward<W>(value);
}

int main()
{
  auto m_enum = A::B::myEnum::E_0;
  A a;
  a.b.e = m_enum;
  std::cout << a.b.e << std::endl;
  setField(a, &A::B::e, m_enum);
  std::cout << a.b.e << std::endl;
}
```

Error log:

`31:31: error: no matching function for call to 'setField(A&, A::B::myEnum A::B::*,A::B::myEnum&)'`

`31:31: note: candidate is:`

`20:6: note: template<class U, class V, class W> void setField(U&, V U::*, W&&)`

`20:6: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:`

`31:31: note: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'U' ('A' and 'A::B')`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You can do e.g. `A my_A_object; my_A_object.b.x = 5;`. Nested objects are accessed as one would access any object. And if you want a pointer to the `x` member, just keep on using the scope operator `::` to dig deeper into the scope hierarchy, as in `&A::B::x`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, it's not resolving my problem. I've edited the question.

Comment: What problems do you have with the code you show? Build errors? Please copy-paste the full and complete output of the compiler into the question as well.

Comment: `no matching function for call to 'setField(A&, A::B::myEnum A::B::*, A::B::myEnum&)'`

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output, including informational notes, into the question body. I'll bet there are some notes that will give hints about the problem and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write:

```
setField(a.b, &A::B::e, m_enum);
```

instead of

```
setField(a, &A::B::e, m_enum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
&A::B::x
```

This gives you an address to `x` inside `A::B`. To evaluate it, you need an object of type `A::B`, which in your case can be accessed by `&A::b` evaluated on an object of type `A`. You'll thus need to levels of dereferencing.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, it's not resolving my problem. I've edited the question.